# Customizing ExpandableView in QML

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I am using `ExpandableView` in QML for Blackberry development.
I want to customize the `ExpandableView` .
For ex :

1.In below image (Screen shot of ExpandableView in collapsed stage)  you can see text 'more' is shown when we use `ExpandableView QML`. which is displayed during collapsed stage, I want to change this default text to some other text

2.collapse(^) and expand image I want to change .

Is there any way to achieve this ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__expandableview.html , there are no properties or methods for setting the text or the arrow images. So, not possible.